# QueryDSL code generation for ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm porting some complex JPQL queries in a large Hibernate/JPA2 application to use QueryDSL 2.3.0, and I'm stuck on one.

My `Client` entity contains

```
@ManyToMany
private List<Group> groups;
```

My existing query fragment is

```
EXISTS(SELECT g FROM Group g WHERE g MEMBER OF slr.groups AND 
             UPPER(g.description) LIKE :group)
```

The QueryDSL code generation has produced the following in my `QClient` class:

```
public final SimplePath<java.util.List<Group>> groups = 
          createSimple("groups", java.util.List.class);
```

The code generation using `SimplePath` doesn't let me use the `in` or `contains` methods to query membership. I think I need a `CollectionPath` instead. Is there a way to annotate the `Client` class so that QueryDSL uses the correct type for querying a collection?

Comment: Possibly this problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/querydsl/xTgCUJ79fgY

Comment: I've been using Eclipse while trying out QueryDSL, planning to move to Maven once I've got used to the tool. Having found this possible bug, I'm going to try using Maven to handle the build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have an answer. This looks like [a bug introduced in QueryDSL 2.2.5, which only happens when working in Eclipse](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/querydsl/xTgCUJ79fgY).

The correct solution is to not use Eclipse to generate the source (don't enable annotation processing). Instead, I'm using `m2eclipse` and generating the source in Maven.

---

For reference, my first workaround was to extend the generated `QClient` class with my own `QQClient` class, which adds one member:

```
public final ListPath<Group, QGroup> fixedgroups = 
                  createList("groups", Group.class, QGroup.class);
```

At that point the equivalent to my original query is:

```
QGroup g = QGroup.group;
JPQLSubQuery subquery = new JPQLSubQuery().from(g);
subquery = subquery.where(slr.fixedgroups.contains(g), 
    g.description.upper().like("%" + group.toUpperCase() + "%"));
query = query.where(subquery.exists());
```

(`query` is the larger query this is part of. `slr` is an instance of `QQClient` brought into the outer query by a left join.)

Comment: We will fix this bug after the holidays. Using the one-jar from 2.2.4 in Eclipse and newer versions in Maven might be an alternative temporary fix.

Comment: Thanks - I only started using QueryDSL a day before the question, so a bug wasn't my first thought. Switching to QueryDSL has massively improved the readability of my query code